# IOS Eureka - Select SegmentedRow programatically

Tags: eureka-forms

I need a method to select/deselect one of the tabs in SegementedRow programmatically. So when I open a form a pre-selected tab is shown.

Similar to UISegmentedControl method: yourSegmentname.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;

Thanks
Greg